# MiKTeX updating and package downloading

Tags: package, latex, updating, miktex

I have installed MiKTeX 2.9 on my laptop, but I can neither update it nor download new packages. Every time I try to update MiKTeX, it shows

[image: Updating error message]

When I try to download a new package, e.g. "abntex2", it shows

[image: Package downloading error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your windows user lacks sufficient read and write permissions in the folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\
```

You can remedy this problem in two manners:

1. When updating MiKTeX, run the program as admin: right click and choose "Run as administrator". Example:

[image: Run as administrator]

2. Set the permissions specifically for the MiKTeX folder: select the `MiKTeX 2.9` folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)\`, right click the folder, and choose *Properties*. In the Properties dialog box, click the `Security` tab. Now, depending on your Windows version, in this tab, you can set the permissions for the users w.r.t. to this folder. Select the user you are using and check in `Full Control` (or something likewise).

Hopefully, making sure you can run and access MiKTeX folder with full permissions, you MiKTeX will update as intended.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx for details regarding user permissions for files and folders in Windows.

Comment: @MarcosPauloMiotti You're welcome. If this fully answers your question, please close it by accepting the answer.